# How to remove UIPageControl from navigationBar?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uipagecontrol

I've got a tableview showing different categories.
Piking one of these categories, it performs a (push) segue to a PageViewController displaying the appropriate subcategories.
I decided to show the UIPageControl in the navigation bar under the title and it works as it should be but going back to the previous controller, I'm unable to remove the dots so they wrongly appear also in the presenting VC.

Here how I've implemented the custom navigation bar:

```
class MyClass {

//MARK: - Outlets

private var pageControl: UIPageControl?
var rLNavItem: UINavigationItem?

//MARK: - Life cycle

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let childView = self.navigationController?.childViewControllers.last
    childView?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = // ...
    childView?.navigationItem.titleView = //...
    self.rLNavItem = childView?.navigationItem

    navigationController(self.navigationController!, willShowViewController: childView!, animated: true)
}

//MARK: - Navigation delegate

func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {

    self.navigationController?.delegate = self        
    let index = (navigationController.viewControllers as NSArray).indexOfObject(viewController)
    self.pageControl?.currentPage = index

    let navBarSize = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.bounds.size        
    let origin = CGPointMake(((navBarSize?.width ?? 0)/2), ((navBarSize?.height ?? 0)/2) )
    self.pageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRectMake(origin.x, origin.y + 18, 0, 0))
    self.pageControl?.numberOfPages = 4
    self.pageControl?.currentPage = itemIndex
    self.pageControl?.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.pageControl?.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    self.pageControl?.hidesForSinglePage = true
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(pageControl!)
 }
```

`}`

Unfortunately I cannot upload a picture due to my profile rate but my storyboard is composed by a TabBarController embedding a NavigationController for each tab. 
 I've tried giving the pageControl a tag value and then removing the view in the navigation delegate method but it didn't work.

Any suggestion?

Many thanks

Comment: I know this is not a great solution but I found that the navigation delegate method was called twice. At the moment I deleted the 
self.navigationController?.delegate = self and used the tag property in viewWillDisappear to remove the PagaControl view

Answer (score 0):

try to set `self.pageControl = nil` in your `viewWillAppear`

Comment: This doesn't work. You can't assign nil to a pagecontrol.